# what is the difference between left join and left outer join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, outer-join

I have created 2 tables as

```
CREATE TABLE table1(customerName VARCHAR(20),custid NUMBER ,order_id NUMBER ,price NUMBER );
CREATE TABLE table2(id NUMBER ,salary NUMBER );
```

Now, I tried to use the queries

```
SELECT t1.customername,t1.custid,t2.salary FROM table1 t1 left join table2 t2 ON t1.custid = t2.id;
SELECT t1.customername,t1.custid,t2.salary FROM table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 ON t1.custid = t2.id;
```

But I get the same output. Is there any difference between them internally in their working ? or are both same!?

Comment: None, `LEFT JOIN` is just the short form of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `OUTER` keyword is optional across most popular SQL distributions, which means there is absolutely no difference between a `LEFT JOIN` and a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`